# How to Intercept Native File System API calls made by web application?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, web, puppeteer, native-file-system-api-js

How can I intercept API calls made by the web application? For example, how can I know the web site uses native file system api and intercept its function when user invokes the above function?

```
await window.showOpenFilePicker()
```

Comment: You'll probably need to show more code than that.

Comment: I illustrate my problem in  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65793488/overriding-showopenfilepicker-with-puppeteer) further, can you take a look?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [facade (aka decorator) pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facade_pattern) to do this.

Inject code into the page using [TamperMonkey](https://www.tampermonkey.net/) to do this:

```
;(() => {
  const old = window.showOpenFilePicker;
  window.showOpenFilePicker = () => {
    console.log('showOpenFilePicker called');
    return old();
  }
})();
```

Comment: Unfortunately this not solves my problem. I illustrate my problem in here further, can you take a look? [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65793488/overriding-showopenfilepicker-with-puppeteer)

Comment: Override the `window.showOpenFilePicker` using the method shown there.

Comment: can you illustrate a simple example?

Comment: The example you pointed to shows it. Instead of overriding the `HTMLCanvasElement`, you override the function you want. Like this: `const old = window.showOpenFilePicker; window.showOpenFilePicker = () => {console.log('intercepted'); return old() }`